# Privacy Batch Api - Understanding and Implementation

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, gdpr, einstein-recommendations

I am stuck on a relatively new addition of salesforce. The privacy attributes DoNotTrack, DoNotProfile and DoNotProcess. Here is the link to the topic: [Privacy in Personalization Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_personalization_builder_april_2018.htm&type=5)

The first question that comes to my mind was: How can i set these values automaticly (automation studio / rest-api / soap-api). Since i did not found a solution that works without programming i stumbled upon that link [Privacy Batch API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/pb-privacy-api.htm).

First of all:
Is this the right solution to set privacy settings for particular subscribers?

And now to my problems:
I tried using this API and tested with Postman. Unfortunately i wasn't able to do any successful call.

For authorization i went to Predictive Web -> Admin Tools -> Manage Api Keys and copied the value of Crimson Kraken Key to insert this value into the Bearer Token. Is this even the right step? Sometimes i saw that people needed to request a call that authenficates them and delivers a token. Do i need to do that? If yes: How?

After that i defined the JSON POST Request:

- Authorization: Bearer XXX
- Content-Type: application/json
- Host: https://app.igodigital.com
- POST: /api/v2/organization/MID-value/privacy

I am very uncertain if the POST String is correct here. I strongly believe its wrong but i dont know whats the right string. Furthermore i have no clue what i have to enter into the body of the call. The example looks like this:
[image]

I am very thankful for every comment that points me into the right direction / other help articles [i did not found one]. Thanks for all that read this question

Comment: What was the response You were getting at that time? After 2 years, I believe You already have managed yourself. I would say this is a very nice question that got few attention at that time. From what I'm seeing, probably the best would be to do those API calls on the Preference Center, that I would say is the best practices.